# Python: return statement doesnt work

Tags: python, function

I am trying to print a list of names using the following program

```
def search():
    with open('business_ten.json') as f:
        data=f.read()
        jsondata=json.loads(data)


    for row in jsondata['rows']:
        #print row['text']
        a=str(row['name'])

        #print a    
        return a


search()
```

If I put the return statement , it doesnt print , but if i put the print statement it works
I want the return statement to work. I want the return statement instead of the print statement

Comment: In Python indentation is part of syntax. Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Return ends the method and returns the value of `a` on the first iteration. Have a look at [this lesson](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html).

Comment: Also, you probably don't want `return` in there, but `yield` instead.

Comment: Instead of `print` you can append in a list and return that list after `for` loop ends.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to indentation problem so that your `return` statement is not working.
Put `for` loop with in `search`

```
def search():
    with open('business_ten.json') as f:
        data=f.read()
        jsondata=json.loads(data)
        for row in jsondata['rows']:
            a=str(row['name'])  
            yield a

data = search()
print list(data)
```

or

```
print list(search())
```

Comment: I tried it , its not working .  it doesnt print anything

Comment: @dipit check the updated code. you need to catch the return statement in some variable then `print` it.

Comment: It will only return the first row. Instead store return data in list and return that list after `for` loop ends.

Comment: This still won't work, after calling return the loop is going to end, so you will only get one result from the potentially many generated by jsondata['rows']

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia then generator will help. i updated.

Comment: @Ashwani Dausodia  could you please write it down

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return from inside a loop, as the method will just finish after the first part of the loop. It seems like you need to print the a, append a to a list of your data, then after the loop has finished, return said list.

Also your indentation is very... interesting. I'm not sure if that's an issue with how you have copied over your code, or if that is actually what your code looks like, however I would imagine the former otherwise it would have never run. Could you possibly edit the question to correct the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want, but you could have explained it better...

```
def search():
    with open('business_ten.json') as f:
        data=f.read()
        jsondata=json.loads(data)
        for row in jsondata['rows']:
            a=str(row['name'])  
            yield a

print list(search())
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of all strings you were printing earlier and return that list.

```
def search():
    with open('business_ten.json') as f:
        data=f.read()
        jsondata=json.loads(data)
    return_data = []
    for row in jsondata['rows']:
        #print row['text']
        a=str(row['name'])

        #print a
        return_data.append(a)

    return return_data


print(search())
```